# opencsv, can't use values with"

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm using open csv to read a CSV that has only 2 columns, example:

```
"valueA1","valueB of A1"
,"valueB of A1"
,"valueB of A1"
,"valueB of A1"
"valueA2","valueB of A2"
,"valueB of A2"
,"valueB of A2"
,"valueB of A2"
```

And it keeps going, so far so good.
I'm having trouble when some of the values on column B are coming with some characters
Example:

```
"valueA1","va"lueB" of A1"
,"valueB of A1"
,"valueB of A1"
,"valueB of A1"
"valueA2","valueB of A2"
,"valueB of A2"
,"valueB of A2"
,"valueB of A2"
```

When my column B has something like a **"** or even in some cases a **:** my open csv loses all the format and instead of saying my next line contains 2 values it shows me crazy things like 36, 48, and it loses a huge amount of content due to that.

How can I specify that these values are inside the colum B and h'es not suposed to assume that he needs to create a new column?

I'm using the simple constructor

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(arquivo));
```

By doing research I saw some of the people saying to use a different constructor, I tried to do

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(arquivo), ',','"');
```

But the result was the same, since the constructor accepts only char I can't do **","**

Comment: You should escape the `"` in the string literals before writing it to the CSV.

Comment: @bali182 You mean enter the file and remove all the " before running the csv? But that would also remove "" that define the csv fields.

Comment: You csv have vrong format. Conect to provider and ask them to fix it.

Comment: What @talex said. It's a "syntax" error in your CSV. If you write it by yourself, then escape it, before writing it to the file, otherwise, ask who created it to fix it.

Comment: My problem is that who creates this csv is another company, and they its the only way that they provide the information, there is no web service or anything like it. I need to read the content of this file and save in to my database, there is no way to work around this problem?

Comment: Ask them about format. Maybe it is not CSV but some other format that just looks alike

Comment: It actually comes as a xls, i'm chaning from xls to csv, they even said that i have to open the file only on excel(since its a xls), and looking on the file is the exact situation i showed in the question.
They said there is no way for then to change the file format or its content.

Comment: It is look like you convert it wrong

Comment: @talex the convertion "looks" fine, but what you said make sense, i'll try to convert using ¢ instead of " as my separator, i'll see if that works, i don't think i will encounter a ¢ inside my csv. Or you would suggest me a different approach?

Comment: CSV support escaping. I dont know how you convert but string `a"b` may be represented as `"a""b"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no official standard for CSV but there is an unofficial one, and the sample you show doesn't comply with it. Values containing the double-quote character should be quoted, and the double-quote characters within the value should be doubled.

```
valueA1,"va""lueB"" of A1"
```

(It's permitted but not required to put double quotes around "valueA1" in this example.) Since you're creating the CSV file yourself, from an XLS file, you should fix the problem in the conversion.

Excel 2007 does this correctly if you save as "CSV (MS-DOS) (*.csv)". I recall that older versions of Excel had an CSV options screen that you might need to play with.

Answer (score 1):

First I still would set the separator and quote explicitly. You said you had a problem with `;`.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(arquivo), ',', '\"');
```

Then there is a data error: a text value `va"lueB" of A1` which Excel for instance would self-escape as: `va""lueB"" of A1`. I do not know what CSVWriter would make of a double quote.

The least invasive would be to correct the data while reading:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new RepairingReader(new FileReader(arquivo)),
                                 ',', '\"', '\\');
```

Here I also specify the escape character for separator and quote.

`CSVReader` uses a `BufferedReader` either passed, or added by itself and calls `readLine`.

```
public class RepairingReader extends BufferedReader {

    public RepairingReader(Reader reader, int capacity) {
        super(reader, capacity);
    }

    public RepairingReader(Reader reader) {
        super(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        String line = super.readLine();
        if (line != null) {
            line = line.replaceAll("([^,\\\\])\"([^,])", "$1\\\\\"$2");
        }
        return line;
    }
}
```

This just overrides `readLine`. It repaces any quote that has a character in front (not backslash, not comma) and after (not comma). The replacement should be a backslash followed by a quote.

This is not a full parser, as then one would implement a CSV reader oneself.

By the way: `FileReader` has no option to set the encoding used for converting the file to Unicode String. The default platform encoding is used. Hence the code is not portable, the file should be in the local encoding. Use `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), encoding)` instead for portable software.